# Wordpress adding custom fields into post's front end

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i want to make a wordpress plugin that will display some content at the end of each post. let's say for example 'Hello world'.
But looking at the wordpress API, i don't find any relevant indications about how to do this.

i don't want a widget, but only a plugin that does only that: displays me a static text at the end of every article.

any idea about how this should be done?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this forum post helps you:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/simple-wordpress-plugin-to-add-actionable-text-after-blog-content-feedback?replies=1

The lines doing the magic are:

```
...
add_filter('the_content','now_what_pjrvs');
...
function now_what_pjrvs($content = '') {
       return $content . $text;
}
```

Where `$text` is the code that you want to add at the end of the post content.

Hope it helps.
Tell me if you need more references.

Comment: @dana: I edited the answer with the exact line of codes that you have to use.

Comment: doesn't work - doesn;t add me any data in my post. i am using wordpress 3.2.1